# Multiple Commands in Exec() in Asterisk Dialplan

Tags: real-time, voip, asterisk, telephony

I am using Asterisk Realtime Dialplan and a FuncODBC call within an Exec() to return a Dial() command.

I want to try and stick a command Set() before the Dial() conditionally depending on if I need to change the CALLERID(num).  Is it possible to have multiple commands in a single Dialplan Exec() ?

If so then how can I piece them all together - seperating each function with a comma seems to fail in Asterisk 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Some dialplan would help clarify what your trying to do, but from what I understood your looking for Execif() (use asterisk command `core show application ExecIf` to learn more)